# How to show new HTML table on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table which is dynamic. I am creating it with JSON data.
There are several requirement according to which I am working one table.

There is a button `view` on which if user clicks it shows up all the non-zero rows, but currently it is showing into the same table which I don't want.

**What I am trying to achieve**

- when user clicks on `view` a new table should gets populated side-by-side or below the main table
- I have already filtering my existing table with non-zero rows data
- Now I am trying to populate that data into new table on clicking on `view`
- by this user can see what he has enter and can recheck his entered records

**Code snippet**

```js
var tableData = [{
    "Item Code": "1978",
    "Item Name": "Alu Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1979",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Alu Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1980",
    "Item Name": "Samosa-S",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1981",
    "Item Name": "SamosaChat-S",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1982",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Samosa Chats-S",
    "Category Name": "regular"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1983",
    "Item Name": "Garam Samosa Chats-S",
    "Category Name": "regular"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1984",
    "Item Name": "Kachori Chats-S",
    "Category Name": "regular"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1985",
    "Item Name": "Garam Kachori Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "regular"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1986",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Kachori Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1987",
    "Item Name": "Dai Raj Kachori-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1988",
    "Item Name": "Baby Kachori Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1989",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Baby Kachori-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1990",
    "Item Name": "Anar Bhalla-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1991",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Bhalla-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1992",
    "Item Name": "Jhal Muri-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1993",
    "Item Name": "Chat Platter-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1994",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Papdi Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "GIFT PACK"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "2402",
    "Item Name": "ALMOND CHBAR",
    "Category Name": "GIFT PACK"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "333",
    "Item Name": "A BR SB EX",
    "Category Name": "EXEMPTED"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "603",
    "Item Name": "AMUL FRESH CREAM",
    "Category Name": "EXEMPTED"
  }
]

function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  var colNum = col.length; //to improve the speed

  for (var i = 0; i < colNum + 1; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    if (i >= colNum) {
      th.innerHTML = "Quantity";
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head");
    } else {
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head");
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length + 1; j++) {
      //here i am adding a class with the name of the category to each items row.
      var categoryName = tableData[i]["Category Name"];
      tr.dataset.category = categoryName;

      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
      if (i > -1 && j >= colNum) {

        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        quantityField.setAttribute("value", "0");
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      } else {
        if (tableData[i]["Item Code"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Item_Code");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]["Item Name"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Item_Name");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }

        if (tableData[i]["Category Name"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Category_Name");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (j > 1) tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");

}

addTable(tableData);
var selectedOption = "";
$("#CategoryName").on("change", function() {
  selectedOption = this.value;
  console.log(selectedOption);
  //getting all item rows so i can target them.
  var itemRows = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");

  if (selectedOption === "All") {
    //If "All" then style all rows with visibility: visible.
    for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
      itemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  } else {
    //If the selectedOption is anything other than "All",
    // firstly i am style all rows with visibility: collapse
    for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
      itemRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";

    }
    /* alert(itemRows); */
    // then getting all rows which have the selectedOption as a class and style those rows with visibility: visible.
    var selectedItemRows = document.querySelectorAll("[data-category='" + selectedOption + "']");

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItemRows.length; i++) {
      selectedItemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }

});

function view() {
  //get all quantity input fields
  var quantityFields = document.getElementsByClassName("dataReset");
  //iterate through all quantity input fields
  for (var i = 0; i < quantityFields.length; i++) {
    if (quantityFields[i].value != 0) {
      //if the input value of this quantity field is not equal to zero then find the closest "item-row"
      //so that we can set this table row to visible
      quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      //if the input value of this quantity field is equal to zero then find the closest "item-row"
      //so that we can set this table row to collapse
      quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  //change the value of the select menu to "All"
  $('#CategoryName').val('All');
  $('#see').hide();
  $('#edit').show();


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form id="indentForm" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="row position-relative">

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
        <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>Chats</option>
          <option>regular</option>
          <option>fastfood</option>
          <option>GIFT PACK</option>
          <option>EXEMPTED</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="save">
      Save
    </button>
      <button id="see" type="button" onclick="view()">view</button>


    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have tried another way also,in which when user clicks on view the view button gets change to `edit` and the table gets populated with the non-zero rows, but again when user clicks on edit my table Data gets resets to 0, I was and I am using `autocomplete=on` for that but on clicking edit its just refreshed my table data to 0

So that didn't work out. Now I have a new idea of populating table side by side one to view and other to edit, just facing issue to create new table on clicking the view button of non-zero data.

**Note**

The main issue I am facing in every approach I am trying is why the data gets reset to zero when user clicks on `view` button.

Comment: if you're using jquery, take advantage of its selector in invoking javascript functions

Comment: @arjayosma how? didn't get you

Comment: see this: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

however, this doesn't solve your problem and it's your choice to code that way though :D
i'll check your issue

Comment: @arjayosma that i know about the id selectors but here not able to create a new table

Comment: you want to view non-zero results into another table right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187472/discussion-between-arjayosma-and-manish-thakur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a second table and clone the rows you need into that one.

So you can add a new table like this:

```
<!-- Add a new table for results -->
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="w-100" id="table-result"></table>
</div>
```

Loop through the not empty fields:

```
var quantityFields = $(".dataReset").filter(function() {
    return this.value!=0;
});
```

Clone the row, add it to the new table and reset the one in first table:

```
let row = Object.assign(quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row"));
tResult.append(row);

for (var i = 0; i < quantityFields.length; i++) {
  //COPY CURRENT ROW IN NEW TABLE
  let row = $(quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row")).clone();
  tResult.append(row);
  //RESET THE CURRENT VALUE IN FIRST TABLE
  quantityFields[i].value="0";
//}
```

}

See this applied to your code:

```js
var tableData = [{
    "Item Code": "1978",
    "Item Name": "Alu Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1979",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Alu Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1980",
    "Item Name": "Samosa-S",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1981",
    "Item Name": "SamosaChat-S",
    "Category Name": "Chats"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1982",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Samosa Chats-S",
    "Category Name": "regular"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1983",
    "Item Name": "Garam Samosa Chats-S",
    "Category Name": "regular"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1984",
    "Item Name": "Kachori Chats-S",
    "Category Name": "regular"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1985",
    "Item Name": "Garam Kachori Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "regular"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1986",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Kachori Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1987",
    "Item Name": "Dai Raj Kachori-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1988",
    "Item Name": "Baby Kachori Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1989",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Baby Kachori-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1990",
    "Item Name": "Anar Bhalla-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1991",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Bhalla-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1992",
    "Item Name": "Jhal Muri-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1993",
    "Item Name": "Chat Platter-S",
    "Category Name": "fastfood"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1994",
    "Item Name": "Dahi Papdi Chat-S",
    "Category Name": "GIFT PACK"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "2402",
    "Item Name": "ALMOND CHBAR",
    "Category Name": "GIFT PACK"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "333",
    "Item Name": "A BR SB EX",
    "Category Name": "EXEMPTED"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "603",
    "Item Name": "AMUL FRESH CREAM",
    "Category Name": "EXEMPTED"
  }
]

function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  var colNum = col.length; //to improve the speed

  for (var i = 0; i < colNum + 1; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    if (i >= colNum) {
      th.innerHTML = "Quantity";
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head");
    } else {
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head");
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length + 1; j++) {
      //here i am adding a class with the name of the category to each items row.
      var categoryName = tableData[i]["Category Name"];
      tr.dataset.category = categoryName;

      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
      if (i > -1 && j >= colNum) {

        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        quantityField.setAttribute("value", "0");
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      } else {
        if (tableData[i]["Item Code"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Item_Code");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]["Item Name"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Item_Name");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }

        if (tableData[i]["Category Name"] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "Category_Name");
          hiddenField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (j > 1) tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");

}

addTable(tableData);
var selectedOption = "";
$("#CategoryName").on("change", function() {
  selectedOption = this.value;
  console.log(selectedOption);
  //getting all item rows so i can target them.
  var itemRows = document.getElementsByClassName("item-row");

  if (selectedOption === "All") {
    //If "All" then style all rows with visibility: visible.
    for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
      itemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  } else {
    //If the selectedOption is anything other than "All",
    // firstly i am style all rows with visibility: collapse
    for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
      itemRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";

    }
    /* alert(itemRows); */
    // then getting all rows which have the selectedOption as a class and style those rows with visibility: visible.
    var selectedItemRows = document.querySelectorAll("[data-category='" + selectedOption + "']");

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItemRows.length; i++) {
      selectedItemRows[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }

});

function view() {

// Delete 2nd table contents
var tResult = $("#table-result");
tResult.empty();
  var quantityFields = $(".dataReset").filter(function() {
    return this.value!=0;
});
  //iterate through all quantity input fields
  for (var i = 0; i < quantityFields.length; i++) {
      //COPY CURRENT ROW IN NEW TABLE
      let row = $(quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row")).clone();
      tResult.append(row);
      //RESET THE CURRENT VALUE IN FIRST TABLE (commented out)
      // quantityFields[i].value="0";
    //}
  }
  //change the value of the select menu to "All"
  $('#CategoryName').val('All');
  $('#see').hide();
  $('#edit').show();


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form id="indentForm" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="row position-relative">

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
        <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>Chats</option>
          <option>regular</option>
          <option>fastfood</option>
          <option>GIFT PACK</option>
          <option>EXEMPTED</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>
    <!-- Add a new table for results -->
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id="table-result"></table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="save">
      Save
    </button>
      <button id="see" type="button" onclick="view()">view</button>


    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: hey..its creating new table but the data of previous table getting to be zero..thats not what i wanted...i have done same with my earlier there also the table data gets reset to 0 ,here also the same issue,that's why i am using `autocomplite=on` show that the first table data remains the same when user clicks on `view`

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer... so you simply need to update the value on first table (see above)

Comment: You want to keep the input value in the first table and create the rows in the second table with value equals zero, isn't?

Comment: If you want to keep the user input value in first table, just look at the line `//RESET THE CURRENT VALUE IN FIRST TABLE (commented out)`, I've commented out the reset now, so the value won't be cleared in the first table.